# Prolog: Order of clauses for finding path in graph

Tags: prolog

I have a cyclic graph with entry and exit nodes for which I want to find out all paths leading from any entry to any exit node.

```
entry(a).
exit(e).
exit(f).

next(a, b).
next(b, c).
next(b, d).
next(c, e).
next(d, f).

/* Cycle */
next(c, d).
next(d, b). 

/* path(entrynode, exitnode, pathtrace) */
path(X, Y, P)       :- entry(X), path2(X, Y, P).
path2(X, Y, [Y])    :- next(X, Y), exit(Y).
path2(X, Y, [P|PS]) :- next(X, P), path2(P, Y, PS).
```

My path2 predicate works great on a non cyclic graph. Now I want to extend it to cyclic ones. All I would have to do is check if a new possible node is already in my list of visited nodes. For this I would add `not(member(X, PS))` to my last rule.

If I add it before the recursion, it always returns false. If I add it after the recursion Prolog tries to find the paths first and runs out of stack. It returns the correct answers but it tries to find more and gets stuck.

Therefore: Where should I add the check or what did I do wrong/what can I do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional argument for your `path2/3` predicate as your third argument is the path being **constructed**, not a list of visited nodes. I.e. you cannot simply add the `\+ member(X,Ps)` goal to the last rule of the predicate as `Ps` is bound by the recursive call. Try instead:

```
path(X, Y, P) :-
    entry(X),
    path2(X, Y, [], P).

path2(X, Y, _Visited, [Y]) :-
    next(X, Y),
    exit(Y).
path2(X, Y, Visited, [P|PS]) :-
    next(X, P),
    \+ member(P, Visited),
    path2(P, Y, [P| Visited], PS).
```

Sample calls:

```
| ?- path(X, Y, P).                        

P = [b,c,e]
X = a
Y = e ? ;

P = [b,c,d,f]
X = a
Y = f ? ;

P = [b,d,f]
X = a
Y = f ? ;

no
```