# Prolog, give a path from point x to the goal

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

This is my code:

```
% A The first link as a predicate
link(1,2).
link(2,3).
link(3,4).
link(3,6).
link(6,7).
link(6,5).
```

So what we did with the path predicate is check from a given starting point check if there exists a path from that point to the goal (which is defined at the top). This gives the correct outcome for all possible values.

What I need to do now is, I know there is a valid path from 1 to the goal, my path() predicate told me so, now i need to return a list of nodes that shows the that path to the goal, so with using `path(L), path([2,3,6,5])` is true.

Comment: Use [`path(link, Path, A,B)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem statement, you

- Have a *directed graph* (a *digraph*) defined by `link(From,To)`.
- Wish to be able to traverse that digraph from some origin node to some destination node and identify the path[s] between the 2 nodes.

This is a pretty straightforward problem that doesn't require `assert/1` or `retract/1`.

A common pattern in Prolog programming is the use of *helper predicates* that carry extra arguments that track the persistent state required to accomplish the task at hand.

Graph traversal, as an algorithm, is pretty easy (and nicely recursive):

- You can travel from node A to node B if nodes A and B are directly connected, or
- You can travel from node A to node B if node A is connected to some other node X such that you can travel from node X to node B.

The trick here is that you need to track what nodes you've visited (and their order), and you'd want to do that anyway, so that you can detect *cycles* in the graph. Trying to traverse a cyclic graph like this::

`a` → `b` → `c` → `b`

leads to infinite recursion unless you check to see whether or not you've already visited node `b`.

That leads pretty direction to an implementation like this:

- A `traverse/3` predicate, `traverse(Origin, Destination,Path)`, and,
- A `traverse/4` helper predicate, `traverse(Origin,Destination,Visited,Path)`.

You can fiddle with it at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/oZUomEcK.pl

```
link(1,2).
link(2,3).
link(3,4).
link(3,6).
link(6,7).
link(6,5).

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% traverse( Origin, Destination, ReversePath )
% 
% traverse/3 traverses a directed graph defined by link(From,To).
% The path taken is listed in reverse order:
% [Destination, N3, N2, N1 , Origin]
%
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
traverse(A,B,P) :-         % to traverse a graph
  traverse(A,B, [], P)     % - invoke the helper, seeding the visited list with the empty list
  .                        %

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% traverse( Origin, Destination, Visited, ReversePath )
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
traverse( A , B , V , [B,A|V] ) :- % Traversal of a graph from A to B,
  link(A,B)                        % - succeeds if there exists an edge between A and B.
  .                                %
traverse( A , B , V , P     ) :-   % otherwise, we can get from A to B if...
  link(A,X) ,                      % - an edge exists between A and some node X
  \+ member(X,V) ,                 % - that we have not yet visited,
  traverse(X,B,[A|V],P)            % - and we can get from X to B (adding A to the list of visited nodes
  .                                %
```

Once you have that, invoking `traverse/3` with all arguments unbound

```bash
?- traverse(A,B,P) .
```

results in finding all paths in the graph via backtracking.

If you want to know all the paths in the graph, beginning at a specific origin node, invoke it with the origin argument bound:

```bash
?- traverse(1,B,P) .
```

And if you want to know if two specific nodes are connected, invoke it with both origin and destination bound:

```bash
?- traverse(1,5,P) .
```

**Note:** because we're building the list of visited nodes by *prepending* them to the list of visited nodes, the path thus build is in reverse (destination-first) order. If you want the path in proper (origin-first) order, just use `reverse/2` in the main predicate:

```
traverse(A,B,P) :- traverse(A,B, [], RP ), reverse(RP,P) .
```

Comment: Swap e.g. the `[A|V]` vs `V`, and you won't have to use `reverse/2` at all.

Comment: @brebs. How would you want to assert the "have not yet visited" property then?

Comment: As done in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53478218/ - I haven't checked in detail, perhaps Visited is better as an ordered set, for which swi-prolog has optimized memberchk code: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/ordsets.pl?show=src#ord_memberchk/2